# Json - Pegar chave a partir de um valor

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu possuo um json:

```
{
    "pendente": 0,
    "cancelada": 1,
    "remitida": 2
}
```

Eu importo dessa forma no meu file.js:

```
const enumJson = require("./dir/enum.json");
```

Gostaria de saber, como que  eu consigo pegar a chave a partir de um valor. Por exemplo, tenho um valor 2, e quero como resultado o dado: "remitida".

Aproveitando, não sei se chega a ser uma boa prática fazer dessa forma, estou aberto a sugestões.

Comment: Não seria melhor usar um array e acessar os indexadores a partir dele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O objetivo dos objetos não é procurar chaves por valores, mas sim valores por chaves. Se você tentar procurar chaves por valores, você encontrará dois problemas:

- Criar código desnecessariamente para um problema simples.
- Se houver chaves com valores iguais, como você saberá qual a chave correta?

Nesse seu caso, o correto seria criar um array para armazenar essas strings. Dessa forma, você conseguirá obtê-las através de um índice (número inteiro).

```js
const array = ["pendente", "cancelada", "remitida"];
console.log(array[2]);
```

Mas se precisa mesmo que seja um objeto JSON, então você deve inverter as posições, colocando as chaves como valores e os valores como chaves. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
const object = {
    0: "pendente",
    1: "cancelada",
    2: "remitida"
};
console.log(object[2]);
```

Mas se ainda assim você desejar procurar chaves por valores no seu JSON, existe sim uma solução. Basta percorrer cada chave e verificar os seus valores com um laço de repetição. No entanto, desse jeito você pode se deparar com o segundo problema que eu citei lá em cima.

```js
const object = {
    "pendente": 0,
    "cancelada": 1,
    "remitida": 2
}

const valor = 2;
let chave;

for (key in object) {
    if (object[key] == valor) {
        chave = key;
    }
}

console.log(chave);
```

Comment: Cara, muito bom. Valeu pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

É possível uma solução mais simples e direta:

Pegando seus dados originais:

```
data = {
  "pendente": 0,
  "cancelada": 1,
  "remitida": 2
};
```

Essa expressão retornará a string `"remitida"`:

```
Object.entries(data).find((key, value)=> value == 2 )[0]
```

#### Explicação:

`Object.entries()` é uma mescla de `Object.keys()` e `Object.values()`, ele retirnará um array de arrays baseado nesse dicionário. O resultado será o seguinte:

```
[
  ["pendente", 0],
  ["cancelada", 1],
  ["remitida", 2]
]
```

Arrays tem o método `find()` que retorna o primeiro elemento cuja função de filtro retornar `true` (ou valores equivalentes a `true`, como strings não vazia e numeros diferentes de zero). No caso o find retornará:

```
["remitida", 2]
```

Oh, sim, a "função de filtro" alí é `(key, value)=> value == 2`, uma função anônima que receberá os dois itens de cada array filho nas variáveis `key` e `value`, o que elas originalmente são. Daí basta testar se o `value` é o esperado com `value == 2`.

Como eu disse antes o `find()` retornará um array (NESTE CASO), e o que queremos é o primeiro item deste (que guarda a chave), por isso um `[0]` após o `find()`.

Comment: Cara. Bem interessante a tua resposta. Valeu mesmo, vou utilizar aqui.